# text breaks through border on safari

Tags: css, safari, mobile-safari

I'm trying to make an indicator to scroll on a modal, but the text is breaking through the borders on Safari, and from I can see all versions.

```
<div class='d-flex justify-center  mb-0 pb-0 overlay' style="width: 100%;">
  <span>Scroll down</span> <v-icon>keyboard_arrow_down</v-icon>
</div>
```

**Here's what it looks like on Safari:**

[image]

[Here's the codepen](https://codepen.io/Corbin/pen/GRjEdWK)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that Safari isn't taking the line height into account, but I don't know why (though I do see lots of line-height bug complaints about Safari when I Google it).

In any case setting:

`min-height: 1.5em`

on this element:

`<div class="d-flex justify-center  mb-0 pb-0 overlay" style="width: 100%;">`

(because the `line-height` on the text inside is 1.5em) should make it look right.

Comment: It's odd though because I wasn't able to put a button in it either. I guess, I'll just have to set a minimum height for it with everything